# Git + Gerrit commits across branches?

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm a Gerrit newb.

So I have 3 branches. A, B and C.

B is origin/master and there is no local for it. I like it that way because it keeps me from starting off on it when I shouldn't.

I edit A and then commit. I then check out and edit C and commit. The active branch is C which I push up to Gerrit with "git review".  ...except it pushes the commit from A also. Totally not what I wanted. These are two different issues which I'm not yet ready to merge.

1. Why did this happen?
2. How can I get the behavior that I want?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you push the commit directly to remote branchC? Hope you expect commit on branch A was not pushed. There is no difference in case of pushing to review branch. The only difference is the remote branch. In case of direct push you would use `git push origin branchA:refs/heads/branchA` (or just simply `git push origin branchA`), and when you want to review it then use `git push origin branchA:refs/for/branchA`. I am not using `git review` but instead i use this form in general: `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/branch`